# Jquery dialog with empty values

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a jQuery UI Dialog on my ASP.NET page:

```
        $(function () {
            var dialog,
              fascicolo = getQuerystring("fascicolo"),
              annotazione = $("#nota").val();

            function addUser() {
                var nota = {};
                nota.fascicolo = fascicolo;
                nota.notastr = annotazione;
                $.ajax({
                ...
                    }
                });
                dialog.dialog("close");
            }

            dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Inserisci la nota": addUser,
                    Cancel: function () {
                        dialog.dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () {
                }
            });
            $("#create-user").button().on("click", function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                dialog.dialog("open");
            });
        });
  </script>
```

This is my div:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new nota">
<fieldset>
  <label for="nota">Nota</label>
  <input type="text" name="nota" id="nota" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px"/>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

This is the problem, the webmethod called with json get **$("#nota").val()** empty! Help me pls... i tried with 
`.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));` 
`open: function (type, data) {$(this).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"))},` solution but nothing...

EDIT

this is ajax call

```
function addUser() {
                var nota = {};
                nota.fascicolo = fascicolo;
                nota.notastr = annotazione;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "dettagliofascicolo2.aspx/SaveNota",
                    data: '{nota: ' + JSON.stringify(nota) + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Nota inserita correttamente!");
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
                dialog.dialog("close");
            }
```

This is the webmethot called by ajax:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
     Public Shared Sub SaveNota(nota As nota)
    Dim conString As String =           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connMySql").ConnectionString
    Dim myConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(conString)

    Dim stringa_ins As String = "INSERT INTO `note_fascicolo`(`fascicolo`, `note`) VALUES (@fascicolo,@nota)"

    Dim dbcomm As New MySqlCommand(stringa_ins, myConnection)

    dbcomm.Parameters.Add("@fascicolo", MySqlDbType.Int32)
    dbcomm.Parameters.Add("@nota", MySqlDbType.VarChar)

    dbcomm.Parameters("@fascicolo").Value = nota.fascicolo
    dbcomm.Parameters("@nota").Value = nota.notastr

    Dim ident As Integer

    Try
        myConnection.Open()
        ident = dbcomm.ExecuteScalar()

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Response.Write(ex.Message)
        'Response.End()

    End Try

    myConnection.Close()
End Sub

 Public Class nota
    Public Property fascicolo() As String
        Get
            Return _fascicolo
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _fascicolo = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _fascicolo As String
    Public Property notastr() As String
        Get
            Return _notastr
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _notastr = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _notastr As String
End Class
```

Comment: Post your ajax call too.

Comment: i added the ajax call, thanks

Comment: It is not clear (at least to me) what you are trying to achieve. Please elaborate what are you trying to append? What, where and when. Something when the dialog is opening, but what exactly?

Comment: why do you use `window.location.reload();`? The advantage of using ajax is there is no need for reloading pages!

Comment: i want to insert a new record nota in my mysql database, with ajax. These records are in a gridview that i refresh with the reload.

Comment: Get rid of ```window.location.reload();```, add the records to the grid only, don't reload the whole page. Simply read the actual value of the input ```nota.nota = $("#nota").val();```?

Comment: the actual value of nota.nota is an empty string, because i can not take the value of textbox on webmethod... excuse my english

Comment: Have you tried to put apostrophes to nota in ajax data? Like this: ```data: "{'nota':" + JSON.stringify(nota) + "}"```? Or is the problem that the input box is empty? The c# class 'nota' has properties 'fascicolo' and 'nota'? [Good example](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/).

Comment: The problem is that the input box is empty, and yes, the class has two properties... fascicolo gets the value from a querystring, and is ok, but nota gets value from inputbox that results an empty string

Comment: No I see the definition of the 'nota' class. The property is named 'notastr' but the json property is 'nota'. Rename ```Public Property notastr() As String``` to ```Public Property nota() As String``` so the javascript object match with c# definition. Or edit the javascript object.

Comment: i edited in a second time to distinguish the class and the property, now is correct but it is not the problem :(

Comment: Ok now ```nota.notastr = annotazione;``` and 'annotazione' is filled on document ready, at that time 'nota' is empty, right? What about filling the object nota property right before the ajax call is performed? Means ```nota.notastr = $("#nota").val();```.

Comment: I debugged the code jquery right before the ajax call and the result is this:$("#nota").val()=""

Comment: Hmmm. No idea. Could be more then this 'nota' on the page? Some preceding one with no value? If this should be the case try to be more specific when selecting the 'nota' from the dialog, e.g. ```nota.nota = $("#dialog-form #nota").val();```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101306/discussion-between-gian76-and-dee).